# Wait for any of two Futures/Runnables/Callables to complete?

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing

How can I add tasks, two at a time, to an Executor (or similar) and then wait for any of the two to finish (ie the fastest), while the other one, as well as previously started tasks, continues in the background?

I know that a CompletionService offers something similar but with that one all I can do is wait for the next one to complete, with `.take()`. In my case that might be from a previous scheduling and not one of the ones I need to wait for.

In pseudo code I'd like

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
Future<?> one = executorService.submit(() -> oneWay());
Future<?> two = executorService.submit(() -> orAnother());

Future theFirstOneToFinish = waitFor(one, two);
// one done, the other one keeps on working
return theFirstOneToFinish;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CompletionService` oversees only those tasks that it submits. In other words, you can create a new one for every pair of tasks you submit and call `take()` to retrieve the first one that completes.

If you're using [`ExecutorCompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html), create a new instance wrapping your `ExecutorService`, `submit` two tasks, and call `take()`.

For example:

```
public Future<String> submitPair(ExecutorService executorService) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorCompletionService<String> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);
    ecs.submit(() -> oneWay());
    ecs.submit(() -> orAnother());
    return ecs.take();
}
```

No additional cleanup is required for the `ExecutorCompletionService`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CompletableFuture`.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
CompletableFuture<?> one = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> oneWay(),  executorService);
CompletableFuture<?> two = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> orAnother(),  executorService);

return CompletableFuture.anyOf(one, two);
```

Comment: The drawback is that now `oneWay()` and `orAnother()` are not allowed to throw checked exceptions anymore. And cancellation is not supported.

Comment: @Holger I don't think they can throw checked Exceptions when submitted to an ExecutorService like in the OP, since he creates A Runnable lambda.

Comment: No, when these methods return a value, `submit` implies creating a `Callable` which may throw checked exceptions. And since you're using `supplyAsync` instead of `runAsync`, you're assuming as well that they return a value.